# Give the number of times for each statement at its end. For the cases of loop headers, just give the number of times it will be checked

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science, data-analysis

```
int b=0;                                                                                       
int i=0                                                                                           
while(i<n)                                                                          
     j = 0                                                                                        
    while( j<i*n)                                                                         
       b=b+5;                                                                                  
       j++;                                                                                        
    i++;
```

How can I find the number of times for each statement (except basic operations in a loop header) at its end. For the cases of loop headers, how can I find the number of times it will be checked in order to show all the steps to derive a Big O notation to show the algorithm analysis

Comment: You just asked this a [few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306580). I'd have been happy to answer that had you taken a moment to respond to my clarifying question... It's frowned-upon to repost the same thing repeatedly until you get an answer. Just post one time and work with people to get a solution.

Comment: @ggorlen I am sorry that I forgot to respond to you. As I am new to stack overflow, I am getting used to it. So I am again sorry about that.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @Buddy No problem, I understand. Does my explanation in the comments in the linked post make sense? I attempt explaining how to solve this there.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah! I did upto line four that line 1 costs 1, line 2 cost 1, line 3 cost n+1, line 4 cost n times but I have no idea after that because it has j<i*n and j is increased by 1 each iteration.

Comment: @ggorlen I got some idea from it but I am sorry that I did not get how to calculate the number of times for loop.

Comment: Well, if I have a loop like this: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` (the same as your `while` loop, essentially), what's the time complexity, assuming everything inside the loop block is O(1)? This is the complexity of your outer loop alone. Then, find the time complexity of the inner loop and multiply them together and you're done. If you're struggling with `int j = 0; j < i * n; j++` in the inner loop, think about the worst case for `i` and use that to compute the complexity relative to `n`.

Comment: @ggorlen so the first loop will iterate if n+1 then j=0 will iterate n times. For the inner loop while( j<i*n) will iterate n(n+1) right?

Comment: Not sure I follow your notation. Can you use [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? Ignore constants like `n + 1` when talking time complexity--that's just `n`. Otherwise it seems like you're on the right track, so if you multiply the inner and outer loop times together, what's your final result in Big O?

Comment: @ggorlen On my observation it should be O(n^3) but I have to derive it from each step of the loop providing the number of times it will be checked. I mean the cost for each statement.

Comment: I agree. It seems like you're pretty much done then since the inner loop is `n^2`, the outer loop is `n` and everything else is `1`.